# How to run unsigned cocoa app build on another mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

OS X 10.9.4
X-Code 5.1.1
I don't have Mac Developer Program account.

I created app for OS X, builded unsigned .app. It runs perfectly and works on my Mac. When I copy application to another Mac with the same version of OS X, try to run but nothing leads. Application icon starts appear in Dock and immediately disappears without any message. Running in the console gives an error "LSOpenURLsWithRole () failed with error -10810", unfortunately -10,810 is an unknown error.

I tried the same thing with a empty application "HelloWorld", it did not run too. Install and run applications from unknown developers in security setting is turned on.

I tried build LASlider example-project (https://github.com/Doshipak/LADSlider), that I use in my project. When I run it on another mac, app crashes like HelloWorld & my project..

Does someone has similar problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What had happened: Safari download invalid *.app from Dropbox with empty app body, same thing happens if you try to transfer *.app with TeamViewer. But result file looks normal.

Decision: always pack *.app in archive.